Spark aggregate on multiple columns or a hash
Supposed I want to drop duplicates or perform an aggregation on 3 columns in my Spark dataframe.
Would it be more optimal to do
 df = df.withColumn(
        "hash_dup",
        f.hash(
            f.coalesce(f.col("id_1"), f.lit("")),
            f.coalesce(f.col("id_2"), f.lit("")),
            f.coalesce(f.col("id_3"), f.lit(""))
        )
    ).dropDuplicates(["hash_dup"])

or to directly remove the duplicates using the columns like:
 df = df.dropDuplicates(["id_1","id_2","id_3"])

Thanks.
LE1: I am asking this question in the context of processing TBs of data with a high cardinality between key combinations. In that case Spark is using the SortAggregate method for it, instead of HashAggregate.
LE2: I also wonder if the data type and number of columns would matter, considering Hash is an Int and would occupy much less memory then multiple String columns.
LE3: Given the collisions within hash, I guess the better option would be to compare using sha2.

Since both functions are doing the same exact thing I would argue for using the dropDuplicates function right away.
Here is a comparison for the execution plans for the two methods.

Method 1


== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[hash_dup#6], functions=[first(id_1#0L, false), first(id_2#1L, false), first(id_3#2L, false)])    +- Exchange
hashpartitioning(hash_dup#6, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=112]
+- HashAggregate(keys=[hash_dup#6], functions=[partial_first(id_1#0L, false), partial_first(id_2#1L,
false), partial_first(id_3#2L, false)])
+- Project [id_1#0L, id_2#1L, id_3#2L, hash(coalesce(cast(id_1#0L as string), ), coalesce(cast(id_2#1L as
string), ), coalesce(cast(id_3#2L as string), ), 42) AS hash_dup#6]
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id_1#0L,id_2#1L,id_3#2L]


Method 2


== Physical Plan == AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[id_1#0L, id_2#1L, id_3#2L], functions=[])    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id_1#0L, id_2#1L, id_3#2L, 200),
ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=125]
+- HashAggregate(keys=[id_1#0L, id_2#1L, id_3#2L], functions=[])
+- Scan ExistingRDD[id_1#0L,id_2#1L,id_3#2L]

As you can see in method 1 spark is having to perform more work in order to first coalesce, hash and then drop the duplicates. While in method 2 spark can go straight into the shuffle and drop the duplicates.
Hope this helps!
UPDATE
As detailed in this blog post the SortAggregate will be used for immutable data types. For clarification, the example above I was using Int for the IDs

could you please swap out the png's for text so it's easier for people to see?

I have to update my description, in case of high cardinality and a huge number of records, spark will resort to SortAggregate, which performance wise is a lot worse then HashAggregate.

Actually, strangely enough, even my test cases with little data resort to using SortAggregate

@bmcristi if you're interested, i could try to run some benchmarks for you using larger numbers of records

That would be interesting, I would expect Spark to do this internally as well, as far as I know it would decide if the keys fit in a hash table or not. But even with 15 records in my test cases I get SortAggregate.

So the reason it resorts to SortAggregate is because of the type of the columns and the functions used. HashAggregate has to have a key of mutable type (Long/Int) and only certain functions are supported.

Investigating this issue again and I can verify the same as @bmcristi . But I still noticed that method 2 does still use HashAggregate on a small dataset while method 1 will use SortAggregate even on a small dataset
